# How to create a wallet without a private key in Ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js

I've been working on a front end for a project and have been trying to understand ethers. My problem is that I need to Mint a coin to the persons wallet who has chosen to mint it on the front end. I cannot get my head around how to accomplish this bc of ethers wallet creation. It requires a private key to create a wallet and a wallet is the only way that I have found to be able to sign transactions in ether and proceed with the transaction successfully. How would I create a wallet using the current connected metamask wallet to sign the transaction. I dont want to ask for their private key for security reasons. Is there something that I am missing?

```
const signer = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);
    contract = contract.connect(signer);
    
    
    const estGas = await contract.estimateGas.AddToWhitelist(['0x353f4592E1f131CaC58c369fA9758ea37283DAf6'],['1']);
    const item = await contract.populateTransaction.AddToWhitelist(['0x353f4592E1f131CaC58c369fA9758ea37283DAf6'],['1']);
    item.gasLimit = estGas;
    item.gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
    item.nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(wallet.address);
    
    const signed = await signer.signTransaction(item);
    const submitted = await provider.sendTransaction(signed);
    const approveReceipt = await submitted.wait();
```

The above code is an example where the signer is not able to sign the transaction because of  an error stating "signing transactions is unsupported".

Answer (score 0):

in order to connect to MetaMask you should use:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
const signer = provider.getSigner()
```

take a look at the ethers [doc](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/getting-started/-%23-getting-started--connecting)

Comment: Ty for your help but that is not the problem at hand. I am able to get a signer just fine. The problem is that a signer does not seem able to sign a transaction when I attempt to do so, instead it gives me a message "signing transactions is unsupported" when using "signer.signTransaction()". creating a wallet is the only way that has worked for me to sign transactions.